# Do Sears Physics and Berkeley Physics Series provide intuition?

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations

I'm freshman of Math major, because we don't have any physics course. But I'm very interested in Physics. But I'm not very sure which is better or say, more suitable for me.

1. Sears and Zemansky's University Physics (10th Edition)
2. Berkeley Physics Course Series (Vol 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Because I have talked to some of my friends who are in the major of physics.

Some said that Sears physics is more oriented to High school level, with lots of pics, examples, hence to recommand me the Berkeley series which is more 'academic'.

Some others said that the Berkeley Series is too beyond for me, because I'm in major of   maths, with very limited foundation of physics.

As I'm more into math, a book   which focuses on the physical intuition would be nice.   This leads me to my question

*"Which of these books is better for gaining physical intuition? Which uses a more indtuitive approach, in other words."*

Comment: Sears/Zeemansky and Resnick Halliday are better than Feynman lectures for an absolute beginner. Feynman lectures are best appreciated once you've already mastered the material from other sources, done problems etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you instead consider Feynman Lectures on Physics. Also, note that Stanford have many freely-available lecture course videos online (their website, as well as their youtube channel.) All the best :)

EDIT: In keeping with the comments posted to this answer, I felt I could add something by elaborating - To begin with, I agree with @Ted Bunn that the FLoP are best suited to give the reader a deeper insight, provided they have "the basics" covered beforehand. Whilst this may be true in general I feel that for graduate mathematicians, developing a new-found interest in physics, it is certainly worth consideration.

As such, and to expand my answer, I'd like to suggests an alternative option: 'The Road to Reality' by Professor Sir Roger Penrose could well be exacly what you're looking for. For starters, he began his academic career as a mathematical physicist. Therefore, it is by his very nature that he presents concepts and also physical intuition from a mathematical standpoint. Secondly, Professor Penrose is undoubtably a deservingly reputable physicist and his text book has served many-a-PhD-student well in gaining a deeper understanding of physical concepts; together with maintaining a firm mathematical foundation. Indeed it is true to say that many (PhD students) see it as a physicists 'bible' for reviewing basic physics that they may have misunderstood or merely overlooked, during their undergraduate study.

Comment: @qftme : Is there a prerequisite for Feynman ? Or I could just use it for the intro physics textbook of self-learning ?

Comment: Xindong Since you are a mathematics major I do not think you will have problems with the Feynman series. He is great for giving physical intuition, which is what you need.

Comment: This question is already closed, but I'll add this comment anyway. I want to respectfully dissent from this answer. The Feynman lectures are great for additional insight once you've got the basics down, but I would definitely *not* recommend them for a first pass through the subject.

Comment: Again despite this question's closure, I feel inclined to comment. @ted bunn Whilst generally I would agree with your sentiment, I feel that in this instance FLoP would be an appropriate read for the OP. Given that he / she is majoring in mathematics, I would surmise that an introductory physics text book would only serve to waste time for someone who could / should be able to appreciate the more obvious mathematical implications of physical equations 'at first glance.' In other cases I agree that they (the FLoP) would better suit a 'physicist' seeking deeper insight, but not in this case.

Comment: @mbq Whilst I appreciate that the rules and regulations of this site are constructed in such a way as to further the standard and reputation thereof, I fail to see why closing a "specific" question such as this, in any way, conteracts that endeavour. To paraphrase, this question simply asks - what would be a good physics text book for a mathematician? Whilst it may be a 'soft' question, I do not feel it is at all too "specific". Answers to this could clearly aid alot of people. I therefore vote for it's re-opening (Although of course I don't currently have the reputation to do so, formally.)

Comment: @qftme -- you may be right. I still disagree, but I don't think that your belief is crazy or anything. I'd go with the Berkeley series over either the Feynman lectures or a "standard" textbook such as Sears in this case, but of course I could be wrong.

Comment: @mbq I'd appreciate your response to my comment above. Regards qftme

Comment: @qftme Sorry, but it just is too localized. Such stuff should be discussed on chat. And I can't reopen bad questions because of good answers, this is just not helping anyone.

Comment: @qftme: mbq is right, questions that ask about comparing specific books are too localized to be of general interest.